# CUDA kernel code does not execute when using shared memory

Tags: cuda

I was learning using shared memory to optimize cuda code.
I followed most of the implementations from Nvidia materials.
But I found that my device code is never executed. Anyone could help me figure out why?
Did I miss something? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <chrono>
#define BLOCKSIZE 16

typedef struct {
    int height;
    int width;
    int stride;
    float *element;
} Matrix;

void initData(float *p, int size){
    for (int t=0; t<size; t++){
        p[t] = (float)(rand()&0xffff)/1000.0f;
    }
}

__device__ float getElement(Matrix a, int row, int col)
{
    return a.element[row*a.stride+col];
}

__device__ Matrix getSubM(Matrix a, int row, int col)
{
    Matrix res;
    res.height = BLOCKSIZE;
    res.width = BLOCKSIZE;
    res.stride = a.width;
    res.element = &a.element[row*BLOCKSIZE*a.stride+col*BLOCKSIZE];

    return res;
}

__device__ void setElement(Matrix a, int row, int col, float val)
{
    a.element[row*a.stride+col] = val;
}

__global__ void shmMM(Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix c)
{

    int blockRow = blockDim.y;
    int blockCol = blockDim.x;

    Matrix Csub = getSubM(c, blockRow, blockCol);

    int row = threadIdx.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x;

    float tmp = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < a.width/BLOCKSIZE; i++)
    {   
        Matrix a_sub = getSubM(a, blockRow, i);
        Matrix b_sub = getSubM(b, i, blockCol);
        __shared__ float A[BLOCKSIZE][BLOCKSIZE];
        __shared__ float B[BLOCKSIZE][BLOCKSIZE];

        A[row][col] = getElement(a, row, col);
        B[row][col] = getElement(b, row, col); 
        __syncthreads();
        for (int e = 0; e < BLOCKSIZE; e++)
        {
            tmp += A[row][e]*B[e][col];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    //printf("debug: %f.\n", tmp);
    setElement(Csub, row, col, tmp);
}

int main()
{
    Matrix a, b, c;
    int size = 1<<12;
    a.height = a.width = size;
    b.height = b.width = size;
    c.height = c.width = size;
    a.stride = a.width;
    b.stride = b.width;
    c.stride = c.width;
    float *a_h, *b_h, *c_h;
    cudaMallocHost((float**)&a_h, a.height*a.width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocHost((float**)&b_h, b.height*b.width*sizeof(float));
    initData(a_h, a.height*a.width);
    initData(b_h, b.height*b.width);
    c_h = (float*)malloc(c.height*c.width*sizeof(float));
    float *a_d, *b_d, *c_d;
    cudaMalloc((float**)&a.element, a.height*a.width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((float**)&b.element, b.height*b.width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((float**)&c.element, c.height*c.width*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(a.element, a_h, a.height*a.width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(b.element, b_h, b.height*b.width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 block(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE);
    dim3 grid((b.width-1)/block.x+1, (a.height-1)/block.y+1);
    //naiveMM<<<block, grid>>>(a, b, c);
    shmMM<<<block, grid>>>(a, b, c);
    cudaMemcpy(c_h, c.element, c.height*c.width*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaFree(a_h);
    cudaFree(b_h);
    free(c_h);
    cudaFree(a.element);
    cudaFree(b.element);
    cudaFree(c.element);
    return 0;
}
```

I couldn't figure it out since there is no reported compiling error and runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since there is no reported compiling error and runtime error.

You won't get any reported runtime errors if you fail to use [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  **I recommend that any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code.**  It's also good practice to run your code with a sanitizer such as `cuda-memcheck` or `compute-sanitizer`, depending on your GPU.

If you had done any of that, you would have gotten an invalid configuration argument error on your kernel launch.  That would have or should have focused your attention on this code:

```
dim3 block(BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE);
dim3 grid((b.width-1)/block.x+1, (a.height-1)/block.y+1);
//naiveMM<<<block, grid>>>(a, b, c);
shmMM<<<block, grid>>>(a, b, c);
```

The problem there is that you have your block and grid arguments reversed, it should be:

```
shmMM<<<grid, block>>>(a, b, c);
```

I'm not suggesting I have fully debugged your application.  But that is the source of the reason for this:

> CUDA kernel code does not execute

These lines of code are also incorrect:

```
cudaFree(a_h);
cudaFree(b_h);
```

but that isn't the source of the problem you are asking about.  The corresponding free operation for `cudaMallocHost` is `cudaFreeHost`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69081503/1695960)

Comment: Ah, I just tried ```compute-sanitizer```, it listed all the errors you have mentioned. And cuda error checking is also a good coding practice I need to learn. Many thanks, Robert.